# Which is the better way to insert HTML tags into PHP code?

Tags: php

I see two methods but I don't know which is better, should I insert a div tag like this :

```
echo "<div>";
```

or like this ?

```
?> <div> <?php
```

Comment: This is a matter of pure opinion. Go with whatever suits you best, or whatever your codebase requires you to

Comment: With `echo "<div>"` you will need to escape all double quotes in the HTML.

Comment: _I see two methods but I don't know which is better_... none of these. You really do not want to insert html tag with php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no right answer to this.

When displaying a lot of HTML, I normally use `?> <div> <?php`. This is especially true for when looping over data from a database, I would use:

```
<?php while ($row == $query->fetchObject() ) : ?>
  <div class="row-<?php echo $row->id ?>">
     //Some more of the data
  </div>
<? endwhile; ?>
```

However, displaying only a little, I normally just `echo` it.

```
<?php echo "Hello, my name is <strong>Joe Doe<strong>"; ?>
```

I would encourage you to play with it and find what you like best.

Answer (score 0):

The text editor i am using has the color formatting, when you are echoing things, it only all comes out the same color, so if you are outside of PHP you get the benefit of the color co-ordination.